# Undo shortcut not working in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, e4

The last couple of days the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> shortcut (Undo) scrolls down a line (a-la emacs). I tried to switch schemes back and forth, change and redefine the Undo in Default scheme, nothing seems to work. Other combinations (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) work fine, other workspaces work fine with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Any tip that will save me from redefining the workspace?

Comment: In which version of Eclipse, this problem occurs?

Comment: Kepler, 4.3.0 I20130314-1330

Comment: Additional: when I use Ctrl+Shift+L to display the shortcuts list, I see that Scroll Line Down binds to shortcut Ctrl+Z and Scroll Line Up to Alt+Z. When I click on them and press Ctrl+Shift+L in order to open the preferences page, nothing opens.
Needless to say that the shortcuts listed in the list below and above (Save, Save All, Select All etc) are behaving as expected. Somewhere (where?) the keys get redefined.

Comment: you might had a Keyboard language preferences changes ,if so that's will miss with keyboard default behavior ( qwerty to azerty ) in some softwares , check this for windows users :  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-or-change-a-keyboard-layout-language-1c2242c0-fe15-4bc3-99bc-535de6f4f258.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key bindings are stored in the file `[workspace]\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi`.

You can search for `Ctrl+Z` in this file. What does it look like? You could try to edit it by hand.

Of course, it is advisable to backup the workspace before.

Comment: I see the file but I don't see any shortcuts defined (I have at least one redefinition).

Comment: With me all key bindings are stored in this file, not just the re-defined.

Comment: I deleted all occurenses (didn't care if they were binded or not :) ) and it did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Deleting the whole file helped me out! (but keep in mind that this also deletes the cache of the "currently opened files" settings; that means after a new start of Eclipse all files were closed). thx!

Comment: thanks@denispyr, it works. for all, dont forget to CLOSE Eclipse FIRST before editing `workbench.xmi` file

Comment: Only deleting the file worked for me.  I had first checked and found no Ctrl+Z in there.

Comment: I could not find Ctrl+Z in the file but I closed the ide and deleted the file. It started working when I restarted the IDE. Lost all cache and changes to the gui but glad its working again.

Answer (score 4):

From time to time, I have encountered similar issues with keyboard shortcuts. They just disappear, or doesn't seem to work as expected.

Until I figure out what the root cause is, I check key bindings.

```
Window > Preferences > General > Keys
```

Check if the key bindings are still valid. If not, then set them and it should work.

Comment: Apparently I cannot check but I am pretty sure that I looked and tweaked there before I post the question.

Answer (score 1):

Window > Preferences > General > Keys 
Look for Undo in the list, if the Binding is empty click on Restore Command apply and close.  That should enable the shortcut.