# Eclipse keyboard shortcuts won't work

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I am using Eclipse Juno, and none of my keyboard shortcuts (e.g. Crtl + *) function at all. I checked in preferences and they're all still set they just don't do anything. This is really annoying, particularly with very commonly used ones like undo and redo. Does anyone have any ideas on how to possibly fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem's solution ended up being pretty simple, kind of similar to the question linked by @Apprentice but not quite, apparently whoever had been using the program before me linked CTRL+Z to another command as well as undo, so I went to (Window->Preferences->General->Keys) and unlinked it manually, now it appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

One of the common issues (if you're using Windows) is accidental swtich of keyboard layout by pressing [ctrl]+[shift]. You can try using this combination again to see if it helps.

If it doesn't, you may want to have a look at this question: [Undo shortcut not working in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927851/undo-shortcut-not-working-in-eclipse)

Comment: @Apprentice Thanks, unfortunately neither of those worked :/ I checked my shortcut list and it's still listed there, and strangely enough I noticed ctrl+s still works for saving, but that seems to be the only one that works